# Ubuntu says USB harddrive should be checked for errors

Tags: fsck

I use Lubuntu 14.04 without a display manager. After logging in on tty1 I get the message

```
*** /dev/sdb should be checked for errors ***
```

I have run `fsck` on the harddrive (`sudo fsck /dev/sdb`) but I still get the warning upon login.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

It's okay. Sometimes the stock checkdisk utilities come in short to solve big issues.

Download testdisk here: [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download)

This thing revives any old chap.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I suspect this should be solvable with standard commands.